# What specific meaning does 'just' have in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

```
    Lewis Carrol, the creator of Alice in Wonderland, was said to have 'a just
 horror of the interviewer' and he never consented to be interviewed.
```

In what sense is the word 'just' used here?

Can you give me any different examples where 'just' is used in the same sense as the above sentence?

(Below is the picture of text from which the line is taken). Thanks to all.

[image]

Comment: "just" as justified, correct, right, fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My view is that the word 'just' is *not* from 'justifiable', which is a different word.

'Just' is related to 'justice', in its pure sense.

'Just' means 'right' in a pure and true sense - honest, fair and even... kind.

Its opposite is 'unjust'.

Justifiable is quite different and means 'creating or finding a reason why something, that already exists, should exist, or is right.'Defensible. A case can be made for it - whether or not it is true.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=justifiable+neaning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

'Just' needs no such justification. It is innately true, needing no explanation or reasons.  It stands on its own, shining with the light of Lancelot, radiating out pure truth and what we know in our hearts, to be fair, true and kind.

'Just' in the sense of a 'just horror' means 'true', it means that the 'horror' is deserved or correct or true.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/just

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just

Other examples (mine):

- The description of the hotel as being 'bijou' was just - it was a real treasure of a room we had there.
- Churchill's epithet 'the british bulldog' was just - for he could certainly bare his fangs at his adversaries.
- Saying that the beach is dirty is just criticism - it's absolutely filthy!
- saying that the girl was beautiful was just praise - she truly shone.
- the girl had a just horror of her tutor - finding that his fangs were gnarly like a vampire, and his breath stank of pickled onions.

Comment: Thank you so much Jelila! Can give me some more examples(sentences) of the use of just in a similar way but attached with a noun, like 'just horror' 'just criticism' etc?

Comment: You're welcome Rohit! I have added some examples. 

Comment: Wow! Wonderfull! Really helpful examples, just what I wanted :D

Answer (score 1):

Just is in its adjective form. It means justified, reasonable.

adjective
1.
based on or behaving according to what is morally right and fair.
"a just and democratic society"

synonyms:   fair, fair-minded, equitable, even-handed, impartial, unbiased, objective, neutral, disinterested, unprejudiced, open-minded, nonpartisan; More
(of treatment) deserved or appropriate in the circumstances.
"we all get our just deserts"

synonyms:   deserved, well deserved, well earned, earned, merited; More
(of an opinion or appraisal) well founded; justifiable.
"these simplistic approaches have been the subject of just criticism"

synonyms:   valid, sound, well founded, justified, justifiable, warranted, legitimate
"just criticism"

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. To be taken seriously, answers will need sources cited for the information provided.

Comment: OK, sure. Sorry I didn't check the rules first. That's copy and pasted from a google search. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The writer wasn't using the word *just* as an adverb, but as an adjective.

e.g.:

> (of an opinion or appraisal) well founded; justifiable. "these
>   simplistic approaches have been the subject of just criticism"